# How to setup opencv2.4.0 with mingw in Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, opencv, installation, mingw

How to setup opencv2.4.0 with mingw in Netbeans? I want to make the setup in windows xp x86 machine?

Updated:
I made a setup as set in this link [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10860352/getting-started-with-opencv-2-4-and-mingw-on-windows-7/10860353#comment17523493_10860353). My program get compiled properly but while executing, it got crahed.

I also Posted the same in this [link-MyPost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13005304/opencv2-4-0-with-mingw-in-windows-get-crashed)

> ***User PATH Variables:***
>   C:\ctags;C:\cscope;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\OpenCV2.4.0\build\x86\mingw\bin;
>
> ***System PATH variable:***
>   ./bin;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\system32\wbem;C:\Program
>   Files\Intel\WiFi\bin;C:\Program
>   Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32\gs\gs7.05\bin;C:\cscope;C:\ctags;C:\Program
>   Files\Vim\vim73;C:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jre6\bin;C:\Program Files\Windows
>   Imaging\;C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin;C:\OpenCV2.4.0\build\x86\mingw\bin;C:\MinGW\bin;

**Update:**

I tried compiling and adding TBB path in windows 7. Even after adding the PATH I get the same issue and the snap shot of the error is below:

[image: Error Image in Windows 7]

I tried the same in windows XP and I didnt get the above error but the application get crashed as before.

Comment: Have you already made MingW work with Netbeans? If so, what have you tried to answer your own question?

Comment: You can try my answer [How to build and use openCV with Netbeans 7.2 . Step by step](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12505581/1322642)

Comment: @Thomas Yes I already installed Mingw. I tried the same setup and steps with opencv2.1 and its working fine.

Comment: Please say what "not working fine" means. You should give me specifics to help you.

Comment: @Thomas Thanks a lot for your response. I have updated my question. Please have a look and your suggestion on it would be grateful.

Comment: Check your system path. Better, post your system path too. I am almost sure it's system path issue.

Comment: ;C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin;C:\OpenCV2.4.0\build\x86\mingw\bin;C:\MinGW\bin; I have added above in my system path. Is it right or do I wanna add something else?

Comment: @Thomas I have updated my question. And the previous comment also contains the same. I replied to u long back but missed "@Thomas".

Comment: @user1317084 With precompiled libs of "opencv" in directory "OpenCV2.4.0\build\x86\mingw\bin", there are always problems. Also I have tried to use this. To compile my programs always worked. When run, the program crashed. This is a common error among programmers who use these libs. try "opencv" to [compile](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12505581/1322642) it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Did you do this?

```
Since version 2.1, OpenCV use the TBB library to support parallel processing.

If you use MinGW as a compile suite you should compile TBB yourself
```

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/TBB

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/MinGW

After compilation, you need to add its path to system path.

FYI, OpenCV 2.4.2 provided with compiled TBB dll for MingW.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Thomas.No I dont know this!!! I didnt compile TBB and add path also. I blindly followed the steps in this path http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10860352/getting-started-with-opencv-2-4-and-mingw-on-windows-7/10860353#comment17523493_10860353. But I never compiled TBB. One more doubt here is I didnt compile TBB for opencv2.1? is it right? Am struggling to compile a sample code for past two days and failed.

Comment: AFAIK TBB is to increase the performance of opencv? correct me if am wrong.. And also if possible could you please elaborate a bit more on this? And what I understand from your answer is to compile a sample program using opencv2.4.0 using mingw compiler suite I need to download and compile TBB? And which path do I need to add?

Comment: Actually, in many case, OpenCV will crash if you don't add TBB. Please follow the links I provided. You will compile TBB into dll and you need to add directory that contains the dll to system path.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I ll try with what u said. And in the previous post I got a response for the same issue. Please have a look and this is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13005304/opencv2-4-0-with-mingw-in-windows-get-crashed

Comment: Hi, am really sorry to trouble you. I tried whatever you said in windows 7. But I get the same error as before. And the snap shot of the error is attached - in my question. Please have a look. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That means your MingW\bin is not added to system path correctly. try copy the dll from `C:\MinGW\bin` to `C:\OpenCV2.4.0\build\x86\mingw\bin`

Comment: Ya tried as you said, still am getting the same error. But in windows xp I didnt find this error. The application just crashes.

Comment: try to reinstall your mingw. i am at the bottom of advice.