# Problems with building opencv 2.3.1, 2.4.2 and 2.4.3, on Windows 7 using MinGW

Tags: windows, opencv, build, mingw, dynamic-linking

Last few days I am struggling with installation OpenCV 2.3.1 on Windows using MinGW compiler. First I've tried newest version 2.4.3 and 2.4.2 but same problem occured. Then I tried older version 2.3.1 but still.

Actually I followed these instructions http://www.pansenti.com/wordpress/?page_id=174 Everything went smooth until building with MinGW. Here is my console output

```
C:\OpenCV-2.3.1\opencv\cmake-release>C:\MinGW\bin\mingw32-make.exe install
Scanning dependencies of target libjpeg
[  0%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jcapimin.obj
[  0%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jcapistd.obj
[  0%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jccoefct.obj
[  1%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jccolor.obj
[  1%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jcdctmgr.obj
[  1%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jchuff.obj
[  1%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jcinit.obj
[  1%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jcmainct.obj
[  2%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jcmarker.obj
[  2%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jcmaster.obj
[  2%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jcomapi.obj
[  2%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jcparam.obj
[  2%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jcphuff.obj
[  2%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jcprepct.obj
[  3%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jcsample.obj
[  3%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jctrans.obj
[  3%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jdapimin.obj
[  3%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jdapistd.obj
[  3%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jdatadst.obj
[  4%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jdatasrc.obj
[  4%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jdcoefct.obj
[  4%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jdcolor.obj
[  4%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jddctmgr.obj
[  4%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jdhuff.obj
[  4%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jdinput.obj
[  5%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jdmainct.obj
[  5%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jdmarker.obj
[  5%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jdmaster.obj
[  5%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jdmerge.obj
[  5%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jdphuff.obj
[  5%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jdpostct.obj
[  6%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jdsample.obj
[  6%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jdtrans.obj
[  6%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jerror.obj
[  6%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jfdctflt.obj
[  6%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jfdctfst.obj
[  7%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jfdctint.obj
[  7%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jidctflt.obj
[  7%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jidctfst.obj
[  7%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jidctint.obj
[  7%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jidctred.obj
[  7%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jmemansi.obj
[  8%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jmemmgr.obj
[  8%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jquant1.obj
[  8%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jquant2.obj
[  8%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/jutils.obj
[  8%] Building C object 3rdparty/libjpeg/CMakeFiles/libjpeg.dir/transupp.obj
Linking C static library ..\lib\libjpeg.lib
[  8%] Built target libjpeg
Scanning dependencies of target zlib
[  8%] Building C object 3rdparty/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/adler32.obj
[  8%] Building C object 3rdparty/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/compress.obj
[  8%] Building C object 3rdparty/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/crc32.obj
[  9%] Building C object 3rdparty/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/deflate.obj
[  9%] Building C object 3rdparty/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/gzclose.obj
[  9%] Building C object 3rdparty/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/gzlib.obj
C:\OpenCV-2.3.1\opencv\3rdparty\zlib\gzlib.c: In function 'gz_error':
C:\OpenCV-2.3.1\opencv\3rdparty\zlib\gzlib.c:518:1: warning: visibility attribute not supported in this configuration; ignored [-Wattributes]
[  9%] Building C object 3rdparty/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/gzread.obj
[  9%] Building C object 3rdparty/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/gzwrite.obj
[  9%] Building C object 3rdparty/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/infback.obj
[ 10%] Building C object 3rdparty/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/inffast.obj
C:\OpenCV-2.3.1\opencv\3rdparty\zlib\inffast.c: In function 'inflate_fast':
C:\OpenCV-2.3.1\opencv\3rdparty\zlib\inffast.c:324:1: warning: visibility attribute not supported in this configuration; ignored [-Wattributes]
[ 10%] Building C object 3rdparty/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/inflate.obj
[ 10%] Building C object 3rdparty/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/inftrees.obj
C:\OpenCV-2.3.1\opencv\3rdparty\zlib\inftrees.c: In function 'inflate_table':
C:\OpenCV-2.3.1\opencv\3rdparty\zlib\inftrees.c:330:1: warning: visibility attribute not supported in this configuration; ignored [-Wattributes]
[ 10%] Building C object 3rdparty/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/trees.obj
C:\OpenCV-2.3.1\opencv\3rdparty\zlib\trees.c:1244:1: warning: visibility attribute not supported in this configuration; ignored [-Wattributes]
C:\OpenCV-2.3.1\opencv\3rdparty\zlib\trees.c:1244:1: warning: visibility attribute not supported in this configuration; ignored [-Wattributes]
C:\OpenCV-2.3.1\opencv\3rdparty\zlib\trees.c: In function '_tr_init':
C:\OpenCV-2.3.1\opencv\3rdparty\zlib\trees.c:410:1: warning: visibility attribute not supported in this configuration; ignored [-Wattributes]
C:\OpenCV-2.3.1\opencv\3rdparty\zlib\trees.c: In function '_tr_stored_block':
C:\OpenCV-2.3.1\opencv\3rdparty\zlib\trees.c:883:1: warning: visibility attribute not supported in this configuration; ignored [-Wattributes]
C:\OpenCV-2.3.1\opencv\3rdparty\zlib\trees.c: In function '_tr_align':
C:\OpenCV-2.3.1\opencv\3rdparty\zlib\trees.c:919:1: warning: visibility attribute not supported in this configuration; ignored [-Wattributes]
C:\OpenCV-2.3.1\opencv\3rdparty\zlib\trees.c: In function '_tr_flush_block':
C:\OpenCV-2.3.1\opencv\3rdparty\zlib\trees.c:1020:1: warning: visibility attribute not supported in this configuration; ignored [-Wattributes]
C:\OpenCV-2.3.1\opencv\3rdparty\zlib\trees.c: In function '_tr_tally':
C:\OpenCV-2.3.1\opencv\3rdparty\zlib\trees.c:1071:1: warning: visibility attribute not supported in this configuration; ignored [-Wattributes]
[ 10%] Building C object 3rdparty/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/uncompr.obj
[ 11%] Building C object 3rdparty/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/zutil.obj
C:\OpenCV-2.3.1\opencv\3rdparty\zlib\zutil.c: In function 'zcalloc':
C:\OpenCV-2.3.1\opencv\3rdparty\zlib\zutil.c:308:1: warning: visibility attribute not supported in this configuration; ignored [-Wattributes]
C:\OpenCV-2.3.1\opencv\3rdparty\zlib\zutil.c: In function 'zcfree':
C:\OpenCV-2.3.1\opencv\3rdparty\zlib\zutil.c:316:1: warning: visibility attribute not supported in this configuration; ignored [-Wattributes]
Linking C static library ..\lib\zlib.lib
[ 11%] Built target zlib
Scanning dependencies of target opencv_core
[ 11%] Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/alloc.obj
[ 11%] Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/arithm.obj
[ 11%] Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/array.obj
[ 11%] Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/cmdparser.obj
[ 11%] Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/convert.obj
[ 12%] Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/copy.obj
[ 12%] Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/datastructs.obj
[ 12%] Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/drawing.obj
[ 12%] Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/dxt.obj
[ 12%] Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/lapack.obj
[ 12%] Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/mathfuncs.obj
[ 13%] Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/matmul.obj
[ 13%] Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/matop.obj
[ 13%] Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/matrix.obj
[ 13%] Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/out.obj
[ 13%] Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/persistence.obj
[ 14%] Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/precomp.obj
[ 14%] Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/rand.obj
[ 14%] Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/stat.obj
[ 14%] Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/system.obj
[ 14%] Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/tables.obj
Linking CXX shared library ..\..\bin\opencv_core231.dll
[ 14%] Built target opencv_core
Scanning dependencies of target opencv_imgproc
[ 14%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/accum.obj
[ 14%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/approx.obj
[ 14%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/canny.obj
[ 14%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/color.obj
[ 14%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/contours.obj
[ 15%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/convhull.obj
[ 15%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/corner.obj
[ 15%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/cornersubpix.obj
[ 15%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/deriv.obj
[ 15%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/distransform.obj
[ 16%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/emd.obj
[ 16%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/featureselect.obj
[ 16%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/featuretree.obj
[ 16%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/filter.obj
[ 16%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/floodfill.obj
[ 16%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/geometry.obj
[ 17%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/grabcut.obj
[ 17%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/histogram.obj
[ 17%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/hough.obj
[ 17%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/imgwarp.obj
[ 17%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/inpaint.obj
[ 17%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/kdtree.obj
[ 18%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/linefit.obj
[ 18%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/lsh.obj
[ 18%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/matchcontours.obj
[ 18%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/moments.obj
[ 18%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/morph.obj
[ 19%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/precomp.obj
[ 19%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/pyramids.obj
[ 19%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/pyrsegmentation.obj
[ 19%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/rotcalipers.obj
[ 19%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/samplers.obj
[ 19%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/segmentation.obj
[ 20%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/shapedescr.obj
[ 20%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/smooth.obj
[ 20%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/spilltree.obj
[ 20%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/subdivision2d.obj
[ 20%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/sumpixels.obj
[ 21%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/tables.obj
[ 21%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/templmatch.obj
[ 21%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/thresh.obj
[ 21%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/undistort.obj
[ 21%] Building CXX object modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/utils.obj
mingw32-make[2]: *** No rule to make target `lib/opencv_core231.lib', needed by `bin/opencv_imgproc231.dll'.  Stop.
mingw32-make[1]: *** [modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make: *** [all] Error 2

C:\OpenCV-2.3.1\opencv\cmake-release>
```

Same problem occured during installation 2.4.3 and also 2.4.2. (crash during linking  opencv_imgproc)

I don't know what I am doing wrong. It seems that I am not including some libraries.

Thank you for any advice

Comment: Paste the output here, don't refer to other sites.

Comment: done..original post is edited

Comment: You did'nt tell Cmake to generate the makefiles for the right mingW compiler environment. It looks like you create VS makefiles. [mingw installing for opencv](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374474/netbeans-7-2-mingw-installing-for-opencv/12505581#12505581)