# QT output is "exited with code 0" and no image is shown

Tags: c++, windows, qt, opencv, mingw

I am working on the following code:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Mat image = imread("C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample Pictures/Tulips.jpg");
    namedWindow("Image");
    imshow("Image",image);
    waitKey(0);
}
```

**Test.pro**

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2013-05-07T10:38:38
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core

QT       -= gui

TARGET = Test
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp
INCLUDEPATH += E:/Jasmin/Yohan/opencv/build/include
INCLUDEPATH += E:/Jasmin/Yohan/opencv/include/opencv2

LIBS += E:/Jasmin/Yohan/opencv/build/x86/mingw/lib/libopencv_calib3d240.dll.a
LIBS += E:/Jasmin/Yohan/opencv/build/x86/mingw/lib/libopencv_contrib240.dll.a
LIBS += E:/Jasmin/Yohan/opencv/build/x86/mingw/lib/libopencv_core240.dll.a
LIBS += E:/Jasmin/Yohan/opencv/build/x86/mingw/lib/libopencv_highgui240.dll.a
LIBS += E:/Jasmin/Yohan/opencv/build/x86/mingw/lib/libopencv_imgproc240.dll.a
```

When I run this code, no image is showing up, the following output get printed

```
Starting E:\Jasmin\Yohan\QTProjects\build-Test-Desktop_Qt_5_0_2_MinGW_32bit-Debug\debug\Test...
E:\Jasmin\Yohan\QTProjects\build-Test-Desktop_Qt_5_0_2_MinGW_32bit-Debug\debug\Test exited with code 0
```

Following opencv related environment variables are added to the "path" system variable

```
E:\Jasmin\Yohan\opencv\build\x86\mingw\bin;E:\Jasmin\Yohan\opencv\build\x86\vc10\bin
```

Why I am getting this issue? My QT creator version is 2.7.0

### Update

This is what my debugger has to say:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't know but I would add `std::cout << "got here\n";` at various points in your code to see where it gets to.

Comment: What does your debugger say?

Comment: @cmannett85: Please have a look at the update

Comment: @john: I put a print statement at the very begining of main. No prints at all\

Comment: This happened with all my 3 computers, while the version which works with VS 2010 works fine!

Comment: If it's crashing before main, it's usually a dynamic linking issue.  Use the Windows equivalent to `ldd` (Dependency Walker?) to see what dlls your app is requesting, and what it's actually finding.

Comment: You are including the libs in your .pro file wrong. Read [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-project-files.html#declaring-other-libraries) how it should be done correctly.

Comment: Have you seen / read my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be doing what it should: waitKey(0) waits zero seconds or milliseconds and program quits. Increase waiting time or put waitKey in loop..

Comment: 0 in waitKey() means forever

Comment: Yes, it is the standard thing, just like "system("pause")

Answer (score 0):

Using the libs in "...\opencv\build\x86\mingw\bin" and "...\opencv\build\x86\mingw\lib

**You can not use the libraries that come with OpenCV-2.4.x.exe.**

As some developers in forums and I find out. On some systems, the precompiled libs of "opencv 2.4.x" can not be used.
To compile your own programs, works, but it crashed if you try to run them. Until there are not functioning precompiled libs of "opencv 2.4.x , you have to compile opencv yourself.

Ignore so the folder "...\opencv\build\x86\mingw\bin" and "...\opencv\build\x86\mingw\lib" completely.

[Using the libs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13052025/1322642)

[How to build and use openCV](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12505581/1322642)