# openCV in Netbeans IDE

Tags: java, opencv, netbeans

As of version 2.4.4 OpenCV supports desktop Java development but I am unable to find any tutorials on how to set up openCV with Netbeans IDE, could somebody point me in the right direction?

Comment: Please let me know if some parts of my answer, could help you. [build openCV with Netbeans](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12505581/1322642)

Answer (score -1):

You can get reference to related topic [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/717283/How-to-Use-OpenCV-with-Java-under-NetBeans-IDE).

Comment: Just don't post a link as answer.